# How can I remove undesired straight line suddenly appearing in the exported image of mathematica?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, image

I'm drawing a picture of some 2D flows (x[t],y[t]) generated by differential equations of x[t] and  y[t]. The code is as follows. The picture I get inside mathematica is like[image]

Something is already wrong here, because around the left red dot(one of the critical point of the flows), there should be many flows around, but mathematica don't show them.

If I export this as pdf, there will be many irrelevant straight lines crossing the whole image. Like this[image]

So would anybody kindly explain what happens here? Why mathematica can't show the right flow? Is that related with the plot range of my parameter t? And how can I remove these undesired straight line in the exported pdf?

Maybe my description of the problem is not so well-organized. If I miss something important, please point it out.

```
Clear[x, y, z, w]
z = 2/5 I + 1/10 ;
W[w_] := Log [w] + Log[w - 1] + Log[w - z];
Criticalpoints = Solve[W'[w] == 0, w];
pplus = w /. Criticalpoints[[2]][[1]];
pointplus = ReIm[pplus];
pminus = w /. Criticalpoints[[1]][[1]];
pointminus = ReIm[pminus];
range = {t, -0.2, 0.2};
bias1 = 0.01;
bias2 = 0.01;
step = 5;
Repartial = 
  ComplexExpand[Re[W'[w]], w] /. {Re[w] -> x[t], Im[w] -> y[t]};
Impartial = 
  ComplexExpand[Im[W'[w]], w] /. {Re[w] -> x[t], Im[w] -> y[t]};
criplus[1] = 
  Table[NDSolve[{x'[t] == -Repartial, y'[t] == Impartial, 
     x[0] == Re[pplus] + bias1*Cos[2 \[Pi] i/step], 
     y[0] == Im[pplus] + bias1*Sin[2 \[Pi] i/step]}, {x[t], y[t]}, 
    range], {i, 0, step}];
criminus[1] = 
  Table[NDSolve[{x'[t] == -Repartial, y'[t] == Impartial, 
     x[0] == Re[pminus] + bias2*Cos[2 \[Pi] i/step], 
     y[0] == Im[pminus] + bias2*Sin[2 \[Pi] i/step]}, {x[t], y[t]}, 
    range], {i, 0, step}];
P = ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. {criplus[1], criplus[2], 
     criminus[1], criminus[2]}, {t, -0.2, 0.2}, 
   Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[pointplus], 
     Point[pointminus]}] /. Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{0.01}], Arrow[x]}
```

Comment: I get step-size/singularity/stiff system errors when I process the first  criminus equation and NDSolve only solves it in domain (-0.2,0.08) before the solution approaches vertical tangent which would explain the errors. Are you not obtaining these errors?

Comment: @josh Oh, Yes. Thank you. When I make the  range smaller than the one error message suggested, everything works.